# split string using dot(.) or exclamation mark(!) but ignore whitespaces at the start of new string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Here is my large string.

`This is Rock Balbao.I am the good guy. I am Awesome! And I am Cool`

I want to split it in like this format

- This is Rock Balbao
- I am the good guy
- I am Awesome
- And I am cool

I don't want any whitespaces at the start of any string.

I have tried following way

```
xyzArray = xyz.split(new String[] { ".", "!" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and also I have tried this

```
xyzArray = xyz.split(new String[] { ". ", "! " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

In first option I am getting correct string but 1st 2 string are not seperated. And in second option I get whitespaces at the start of 3rd and 4th element of the xyzArray

Comment: what's the difference between  the first and the second instruction

Comment: Can't you see space in string array?

Comment: sorry it's not evident

Comment: That's why I mentioned the detail description below and told explicitly what result I get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
string[] xyzArray = Array.ConvertAll(
    xyz.Split(new String[] { ".", "!" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
    x => x.TrimStart()
);
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/MTjKBH) of it.

Simply put, you trim the space before the string AFTER splitting it.

Comment: @RockBalbao [*TrimStart()*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) without parameters: (from the page linked) *white-space characters are removed instead*

Comment: Thanks a lot @xanatos

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the `char` array to this `var xyzArray = xyz.Split('.','!');`

```
 var xyz = "This is Rock Balbao. I am the good guy. I am Awesome! And I am Cool";
        var xyzArray = xyz.Split('.','!');
        for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.Length; i++)
        {
            xyzArray[i] = xyzArray[i].Trim(); 

        }
```

**Update**
Just as an answer to your ConvertAll is not much faster than a simple loop

just try the fololwing code and you will see yourself  that  invoking delegates under the hood is more more time consuming than a direct a mrthod

```
var xyz = "This is Rock Balbao. I am the good guy. I am Awesome! And I am Cool";
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var xyzArray = xyz.Split('.','!');


        for (int i = 0; i < xyzArray.Length; i++)
        {
            xyzArray[i] = xyzArray[i].Trim(); 

        }
         sw.Stop();

            //end test1 
            var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            string[] xyzArray1 = Array.ConvertAll(
    xyz.Split(new String[] { ".", "!" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
    x => x.TrimStart()
);
        sw1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Total milliseconds : " + sw.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("Total milliseconds (ConvertAll) : " + sw1.ElapsedTicks);
```

The direct method call is **more ~ 50 X faster** (I have iterate the test many times )

BTW this is `ConvertAll` under the hood

```
public static TOutput[] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[] array, Converter<TInput,TOutput> converter) {
    if( array == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    if( converter == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("converter");
    }
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<TOutput[]>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<TOutput[]>().Length == array.Length);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    TOutput[] newArray = new TOutput[array.Length];
    for( int i = 0; i< array.Length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = converter(array[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Iterating a loop for 1000 records(If I have) is not a optimal solution.

Comment: Yeah I know. But what inbuilt does faster that you can't perform in inline coding

Comment: no no no take LINQ for example sometimes is 10x slower than a simple loop

Comment: and In 10000 records or more LINQ is much faster than any loop. I have tried this in real time example. And where I am concern small data or simple loop there isn't many difference than 1-2 seconds at max. But when bulk data or a great number of data is available then it may result in 5-10 secs minimum delay. And I prefer optimized coding rather than bulking lots of code which can be achieved by a line. They make these functions for us. So If we aren't using it then who will use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] xyzArray = Array.ConvertAll(xyz.Split(new char[] { '.', ',', '!' },     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), x => x.TrimStart());
```

first, it split the input string into array with the delimiters provided in character array and the part x=>x.TrimStart() (it is lambda expression. you can read this as x will be such an item that x will be trimmed on start) which trims at the beginning of  each string of xyz array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var str = "This is Rock Balbao.I am the good guy. I am Awesome! And I am Cool";
var formattedString = str.Split(new[] { '.', '!' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Select(x => x.TrimStart());
```